# adding textviews to linear layout in .java file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am having linear layout with orientation horizontal in my XML file and i am trying to add text views using below code.

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("Sample");
myLinearLayout.addView(tv);
```

Adding 5 text views in the similar fashion looks fine but if am trying to add more text views they are moving out the screen.
I know using horizontal orientation aligns all views in horizontal direction. But how can i make changes to my design/code so that, the hidden text views automatically moves to the next line.
Can anyone suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is either horizontal or vertical, but no both.

You can use `GridLayout`, maybe this fits your needs better.

Comment: I love this simple idea. I forgot that Grid Layout aligns if there is no space. Thanks for this. Let me try it

Comment: Yes it worked but i am checking on it still.
I am displaying 26 alphabets. When i tried numcolumns as autofit, only 2 columns are getting arranged. And when i try to specify a number(say 7) the last row(no of items = 5) is giving me a problem.
I am trying to make it align to center. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you help me in this issue too

Comment: I don't really know, what you mean.

Comment: look at this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/  . I tried the sample but with android:numColumns as 7.( If i am not using it am getting only 2 items per row.) and the last row is left with only 5 elements which are getting aligned to left. Can you suggest me to make the five items in the last row to be aligned to center

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. my best guess is, add before the first item in the last row some dummy item.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to set main layout orientation in xml file to Vertical and then add new LinearLayout in programmatically with 5 textview's in each rows as:

```
 LinearLayout innerlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 innerlayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 innerlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 innerlayout.addView(tv);
 innerlayout.addView(tv1);
 ....
// add innerlayout to main layout myLinearLayout
  myLinearLayout.addView(innerlayout);
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But number of textviews in each row should not be fixed. It must aligned if there is no space in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `TextView` using a loop. Inside the loop you check to see if the x coordinate of right edge of the `TextView` is equal to the width of the screen. If so, you vary the y coordinate a certain amount you want, and you keep adding `TextViews`. You will have to change your `ViewGroup` to one that is not as restrictive (i.e. `RelativeLayout`)